# Can Jest's beforeAll wait until its describe scope to execute?

Tags: jestjs

I've been baffled for the last few days by how Jest deals with `beforeAll` inside `describe` blocks. I want each `describe`'s `beforeAll` to only execute when it's time to run the tests inside that `describe`.

I've written this test file (test test file?):

```js
async function wait1sec() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

async function logWait(i, isDescribe = false) {
  console.log(`before wait inside ${ isDescribe ? 'describe' : 'it' } #` + i);
  await wait1sec();
  console.log(`after wait inside ${ isDescribe ? 'describe' : 'it' } #` + i);
  expect(true).toEqual(true);
}

function logSync(i, isBefore = false) {
  console.log(`synchronous function ${ isBefore ? 'before' : 'it' } #${ i }`);
}

describe('async behavior', () => {
  describe('block 1', () => {
    const i = 1;
    beforeAll(() => logSync(i, true));
    it('sync test in block 1', () => logSync(i));
  });
  
  describe('block 2', () => {
    const i = 2;
    beforeAll(() => logSync(i, true));
    it('sync test in block 1', () => logSync(i));
  });

});
```

You can see the remnants of the fact that I was testing this in the context of async behavior but it turns out that it's confusing even without async.

What I hope get is:

```
synchronous function before #1
synchronous function it #1
synchronous function before #2
synchronous function it #2
```

What I actually get is

```
synchronous function before #1
synchronous function before #2
synchronous function it #1
synchronous function it #2
```

What's even worse is that if I skip the second block (with `xdescribe`), the second `beforeAll` still runs!

So I guess it's not that confusing, I guess it's just pretty clear how it works, it's just not the way I want it to work.

Is there any way, short of simply putting my "beforeAll" code inside my first test of the block, to get the result I want?

---

Note: For a bit of context, I'm using these tests to interact with an external REST API to test how I've set up a workflow. In other words, I'm not testing my own code, and all the interactions with the server are real and result in real CRUD transactions. They're not significant, and they're easy to clean up, so it's a safe and controlled thing to be doing. And my tests build on each other, from one `describe` to the next (i.e., the page I'm working with is created once, before the very first test, and modified with the REST API throughout the remainder) which means that a `beforeAll` in `describe` #2 running before the tests in `describe` #1 can mess up the whole thing. (Especially if I'm trying to skip blocks with `xdescribe`!)

Comment: This kind of stateful integration tests is generally discouraged so this is edge case that the framework doesn't cover. I'm not sure if it's documented but that's something that could be expected. beforeAll and beforeEach are guaranteed to run before tests and they do that. Moreover, if they fail, tests won't stop even with `bail`, this is one of known Jest pitfalls that likely doesn't suite your case too. For what you want to do, just add another one `it` to the beginning that does the setup and make sure you enable `bail` for stateful tests.

Comment: it seems like even in a "correct" (stateless) testing environment, a `beforeAll` that runs only before its block is executed would not be an edge case? i guess I must be wrong.

Comment: I just want to point out that `beforeEach` applies only to tests defined within the same `describe` scope it is defined in. Perhaps that's the function you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`-i` flag](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--runinband) for run your test sequentially;
Also You can wrap your describe blocks into IIFE (or add function for that):

```js
describe('async behavior', () => {
  (() =>
    describe('block 1', () => {
      ...
    }))();

  (() =>
    describe('block 2', () => {
      ...
    }))();
});
```

and it will work as You expect, but I'm not sure is it a good practice. Maybe this way will create some other logical errors for some other async behaviour;